# Converting string to an array in bash with positional values

Tags: bash, unix

I tried to look through a lot of similar questions but I have a specific query. I have two or more sets of strings (space separated values). I want to loop through

```
firstString="f1 f2 f3 f4"
secondString="s1 s2 s3 s4"
```

I want something like

```
f1-s1
f2-s2
f3-s3
f4-s4
```

(in a single loop)

I must be able to take the positional value of the second and further arrays in a single loop.

Comment: Have you tried associative arrays? (bash >=4.0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash - determine a substring in one variable when an associated substring is known in another variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600187/bash-determine-a-substring-in-one-variable-when-an-associated-substring-is-know)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an exact duplicate, but that the answers from that question should help answer this one as well.

Comment: Associative array is a very good concept and could also be used in similar issues(depending on the type of requirement). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you first replace all spaces with a new-line, using `tr` so that you have each value on a separate line, then `paste` will solve your problem:

```
$ cat a b
f1
f2
f3
f4
s1
s2
s3
s4

$ paste -d- a b
f1-s1
f2-s2
f3-s3
f4-s4
```

Pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

firstString='f1 f2 f3 f4'
secondString='s1 s2 s3 s4'

read -ra FIRST <<< "$firstString"
read -ra SECOND <<< "$secondString"

index=0
for i in ${FIRST[@]}
do
    echo $i-${SECOND[$index]}
    ((index++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was looking for the pure bash solution you gave as I can take in as puch pairs of string as I wish. The non-pure solution also works for known inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of bash built-in arrays:

```
first=(f1 f2 f3 f4)
second=(s1 s2 s3 s4)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#first[*]}; i++ )); do
    echo ${first[$i]}-${second[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Although we know the input. they are not in the form of arrays but strings. Also note that it can be more than 2 sets of string

Comment: @explorer: The input does not need to be an array already. If they're strings you simply put their content inside the parantheses: `str="f1 f2 f3 f4"; strArr=($str)`. It's that simple. As for the more than 2 sets, just add "third", "fourth" and so on... :)

Comment: This is a very elegant way of creating arrays. Thanks for this useful tip.

Answer (score 0):

see the test with awk below:

```
kent$  firstStr="f1 f2 f3 f4"
kent$  secondStr="s1 s2 s3 s4"

#now we have two variable


kent$  echo 1|awk -v two=$secondStr -v one=$firstStr '{split(one,a);split(two,b);for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]"-"b[i]}' 
f1-s1
f2-s2
f3-s3
f4-s4
```

Comment: The solution is very useful but I am loking for two or more pair of strings in which case this might be a little diffcult to use

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in a portable manner:

```
set $firstString
for s in $secondString; do
  echo "$1-$s"
  shift
done
```